# Subscript out of range, even though I have specified ranges and worksheets

Tags: vba

I am recieving a subscript out of range error for the last piece of logic in my code:

```
Sub Extract_Bank_Amount()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, lastcell As Range
Dim lRow As Long, i As Long

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Bank Statement")

Set rng1 = wb.Sheets("Payroll Journal").Range("B1")
Set rng2 = wb.Sheets("Payroll Journal").Range("B3")
Set lastcell = wb.Sheets("Proof").Range("C3" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)


 wb.Sheets("Bank Statement").Activate

 With ws

    lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

       For i = 2 To lRow

           If .Range("A" & i).Value = rng1 Then
           If .Range("C" & i).Value = rng2 Then
                lastcell = .Range("B" & i).Value
           End If
           End If
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

It gives me a subscript out of range at this line:

```
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Bank Statement")
```

I appreciate any help, thanks. [link to screenshot of sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBrd0.png)

Comment: Yes. Search for `Workbook.name`, `Like` operator and wildcards. Come back after you did your research with specific questions and code examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *looks* like the name of your Bank Statement tab has a space appended to the end.

i.e.

"Bank Statement "
vs
"Bank Statement"

I have tested your code and it works without a problem, so that could be the answer.

Edit:

To find the last cell +1 in column C as assign to range variable, change the below:

`Set lastcell = wb.Sheets("Proof").Range("C3" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)`

to

`Set lastcell = wb.Sheets("Proof").Range("C5000").End(xlUp).Offset(1)`

As long as your expected last cell is lower than 5000 this should work. Your `Range()` will need to be larger than your highest expected row. If you expect to have 10 rows of data `Range("A50")` would work, but if you have 10,000 rows, `Range("A10001")` would be required, etc.

Comment: I tried removing the space in the sheet name, and editing my code accordingly. However, now I am recieving the same error at line: Set lastcell = wb.Sheets("Proof").Range("C3" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

Comment: @yossup is your expectation that lastcell = the last row (+1) in column C?

Comment: @yossup I have edited my original answer with a solution.

Comment: Ha, it turns out my Proof tab had an extra space! thanks N Hanson